# Como centralizar uma imageView na tela via código?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Eu criei uma `imageView`via código  e gostaria de saber como centralizar ela na tela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Isso vai depender do tipo de layout que você esta usando.Mas tente usar esse:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
mLayoutParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
ImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```